# str' object has no attribute 'text' error came when i am trying web scraping of nokri.com using selenium

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was doing webs craping of `nokri.com` using selenium, after getting the elements using xpath when I am trying it to put in for loop I am getting error this is my code

```
job_details=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="title fw500 ellipsis"]')
job_details
for i in job_details
   i=i.text    
   job_details.append(i)     
job_details
```

I am getting `str` object has no attribute `'text'` error
elements I got already but not sure why I am getting this error

I tried with range(len) also but then I got `int` object has no attribute `'text'` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `i` is a `str` already.
So you dont have to do `i.text`.

Try removing the line

```
i = i.text
```

If that doesn't do, please share the full error traceback.

Also, I wouldn't recommend to use `job_details` variable (that you are reading) to also write your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `:` in loop. Also, you should initialize `job_details`.

Please use `.get_attribute('innerText')`

**Code :**

```
job_details_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='title fw500 ellipsis']")
job_details = []
for i in job_details_list:
    a = i.get_attribute('innerText')
    print(a)
   job_details.append(a)
```

and print it like this :

```
print(job_details)
```